# Why are the metatags from news missing?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

**TYPO3 6.2.33**, **ext:news 3.2.8**

On the detail page the view of the news-plugin uses the opengraph partial to set the og-metatags. These tags are added to the metatag array of the pagerenderer (seen in vardump in the news VH `n:metaTag`),

But in the resulting HTML none of these tags appear. 
Some metatags, set in Typoscript like `page.meta.title` and which are in the array before, are visible.

If I modify the n:meataTag-VH to add these meatatags also to the footer (`$pageRenderer->addFooterData(...)`), they appear in the footer area of the generated page.

A similar configuration with TYPO3 7.6.22 and ext:news 5.3.3 does work ('og:'-metatags are set from news-detailed-template with the `n:metaTag`-VH)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer that as you don't give a lot of information about the site yourself. 6.2 is end of life as well. Things improved in the meantime.

For testing try to remove the whole TypoScript and only use some basic like

```
page = PAGE
page.10 < styles.content.get
```

Does it work then? If yes, it is your site setup.

Comment: It's the same with a 'naked' page. I have a workaround: I copied the n:metaTag-VH from ext:news and replaced the call to `$pageRenderer->addMetaTag()` with a call to `$pageRenderer->addHeaderData()`. Then I copied the Opengraph-partial and changed the namespace to mine. It is a workaround, but why is it needed?  I assume a general problem in the 6.2 (we use ELTS!), as it seems that the metatags are pushed to output buffer before content rendering, but that would mean in all 6.2 installations the n:metaTag VH never had worked. And why are headerdata rendered afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on a TYPO3 6.2.31 site. The tx_news extension did not render the og and meta description inside the header tag.

Below you can find a solution for this problem:

Open:
news/Classes/ViewHelpers/MetaTagViewHelper.php

On line 84 you can find:

```
$pageRenderer->addMetaTag($this->tag->render());
```

Renamed the line to:

```
// Will not render the meta tags on TYPO3 6.2.X:
//$pageRenderer->addMetaTag($this->tag->render());
// Below line is a workaround and will place the meta tags right above the </head>.
$pageRenderer->addHeaderData($this->tag->render());
```